# Youth is wasted on youth

Tags: riddle, word

Alex went through a colourful phase when he was young:

> First he fired guns,
>   next, after a street drug,
>   he went to pick pockets often,
>   becoming adept at causing fractures,
>   he'd contrive evidence against the innocent,
>   and then he had a basic raw material for arson.

What was he up to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like he was

> Playing snooker

First he fired guns,

> Taking shots.

next, after a street drug,

> Pot.

he went to pick pockets often,

> Also, when there is no referee, players must pick the ball out of the pockets themselves to reset the game. (clarified by Tom)
>  **Original:** Picking pockets into which to pot the balls. (only really makes sense in pool)

becoming adept at causing fractures,

> At the start of each game he would **break**.
>  Also, a succession of pots by a single player is also called a **break**. (clarified by Tom)

he'd contrive evidence against the innocent,

> Each game is called a **frame**.

and then he had a basic raw material for arson.

> Eventually he would win **matches**.

First line (thanks Stiv for drawing my attention in the comments)

> The term **colourful** could refer to the colours of the balls.
>  Perhaps Alex refers to Alex Higgins.

Comment: This might also explain the 'colourful' phase...

Comment: All good and either. Own thinking: l3 rot13(vs ab ersrerr, yvsgvat gur onyy bhg bs cbpxrgf), l4 rot13(frdhrapr bs cbgf). Yes to first line.

Comment: Thanks for completely solving this hexomino. I could've (taken time and) appended something like, he was - 'in debt, scared, inexperienced, study depressed, sad, [elite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/pink), and a 7th line, he was going to a furnace - had money', to each line.